# How to read Opportunity Old and New Values from OpportunityField History?

Tags: apex, soql, batch, opportunity-history

This is my soql query for retrieveing the old and new values form opportunityFieldHistory

```
     List<Opportunity> opp = [Select oId, Name,Amount, (Select ID,  
     OldValue, NewValue from OpportunityFieldHistory) from Opportunity]; 

     System.debug(opp);
```

How to read old vale and new from from that?

Thanks,Sekhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple. You just need a nested for loop here

```
List<Opportunity> oppList= [Select Id, Name,Amount, (Select ID, OldValue, NewValue from Histories) from Opportunity];
for(Opportunity opp : oppList) {
    for(OpportunityFieldHistory ofh : opp.Histories) {
          system.debug(ofh.oldValue+'----'+ofh.NewValue );
    }

}
```

Comment: i got the error like this Line: 1, Column: 28
(Select ID, OldValue, NewValue from OpportunityFieldHistory) from Opportunity ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:61 Didn't understand relationship 'OpportunityFieldHistory' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: @subhash our relationship name is incorrect. Check my updated answer.